# How to calculate years of and months of experience in different columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

say this column (d) is the date of joining and I want to calculate years of experience and months in different columns. I really need help on that.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using ? Please tag properly

Comment: Are you looking to do this as part of a query? Or to "store" this data (say via DB provided functionality such as computed columns)?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask maybe you will get more answers...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server, and as per @Damien_The_Unbeliever's comments this depends on how you are wanting to work with the data. Assuming also that its part of query, here is some T-SQL that will do the job:

```
declare @d datetime = dateadd(mm,-6,getdate())

select  
    datediff(yy,@d,getdate()) Years, 
    datediff(mm,@d,getdate())- (datediff(yy,@d,getdate())*12) Months
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
 select @JoinDate ,Datediff(yy, @JoinDate,getdate()) [year] ,Datediff(month, @JoinDate,getdate())%12 [month]
```